# How do I find the path of a windows .lnk file that have been used to open the python script?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

Is there a way to find the specific windows shortcut that has been used to run the python file?

Comment: Probably not...

Comment: Yeah, didn't think so. Ah well. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: It depends on the command line in the shortcut's "Target".

Comment: If it explicitly runs `"path\to\python.exe" "path\to\script.py"`, then yes, it's possible to get the LNK path by calling `GetStartupInfo` and getting `lpTitle`. In this case the `dwFlags` field includes `STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME`.

Comment: You can also get the LNK file if the command line runs the script directly and .py files are associated with a ProgId that directly executes python.exe. But generally Python 3 associates scripts with py.exe, which currently doesn't preserve the title in the `STARTUPINFO` when it executes python.exe.